# Image width/height transition not working

Tags: css, css-transitions

Using a transition when enlarging an image doesn't seem to work in chrome.

HTML:

```
<img src="foobar.png">
```

CSS:

```
        img
        {
            float: left;
            margin-right: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            width: 200px;
            -webkit-transition: width 1s ease, height 1s ease;
        }
        img:hover
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Dk4D/

What is wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It won't work with percentages it seems. Also, if you wish to transition `height` as well, you need to declare it in the orignal `img` styling. Shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/6Dk4D/1/ it works if you specify a `width` in pixels for the hover.

Edit: If you specify the first `width` as a percentage then the second can be defined with a percent as well and still work. **Thank you Tyilo**

Comment: It also works if ou specify both width values as percentages.

Comment: Probably related to this bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104787

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `max-width` trick. Set a high `max-width` amount on the hover and the original image width will be respected by the transition.

http://codepen.io/rustydev/pen/BKOBNZ

Comment: that link is broken now.